# Search the string in entire file system in Aptana Studio-3

Tags: aptana3

I'm using Aptana studio 3 for my project developed using codeigniter.

I want to search for the string in the entire directory. How to do that?

I tried with `ctrl+H`, one dialog box is opened and I have entered the value for search but it shows `0 matches` even if there is a match.